# Inline Conditional Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, formula, inline-visualforce, conditional

I have a simple question that seems to be escaping me at the moment...

The typical way I use inline conditionals is: `{!IF(booleanValue,"SOMECONTENT-IF VALUE IS TRUE", "SOMEOTHERCONTENT-IF VALUE IS FALSE")}`

With the below conditional, how is it reading the second boolean value '00T'?

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!list}" var="item">
    <apex:column headerValue="Created By">
        <apex:variable var="field" value="{!IF(BEGINS('00a', '00T'), 'Owner.Name', 'CreatedById')}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!item[field]}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

UPDATE:
I wasn't looking at the structure correctly. This is saying:

IF **'00a' beings with '00T'** then show Owner.Name. IF NOT show CreatedByID.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Right now your conditional just reads `IF(false, ...)}` which just ultimately simplifies to `'CreatedById'`.

Comment: Updated question with more code. I assume it is saying if the 'item' begins with 00a then...

Comment: No, it's just checking if `'00a'` begins with `'00T'`, which is always false. Perhaps `'00a'` was meant to be `item.Id`, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BEGINS('00a', '00T')` always returns false, as it will try to search `00T` within `00a`

Put your logic properly like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!list}" var="item">
    <apex:column headerValue="Created By">
        <apex:variable var="field" value="{!IF(BEGINS(<field To Compare>, <value to compare>), Owner.Name, CreatedById)}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!item[field]}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: @santau thank you! I had a brain lapse. Both of you guys are correct, I updated my question with the right answer

Answer (score 1):

What the formula you have is actually checking is if the string `'00a'` begins with the string `'00T'`, which is always `false`. So you could replace the current merge field in its entirety with `{!'CreatedById'}`.

A more likely intent would be if `list` has a mixed collection of `SObject` records, and you're not sure of the type. In that case, you might want to check if the record is a `Task` (Id begins with `'00T'`) or some custom object (Id begins with `'00a'`). If that's the case, your formula would look more like:

```
IF(BEGINS(item.Id, '00T', 'Owner.Id', 'CreatedById'))
```

Depends on how many object types you have to handle, how exactly you would proceed. But that's the idea.